# Drools: Using sub-queries in forall

Tags: drools

I'm trying to essentially define an always finally (similar to CTL) query operation using Drools.  The tree is composed of nodes (called `Artifact`s) that are annotated with a path id.  Every split in the tree (a parent with more than one child) is represented by generating a new path id and inserting the fact `SplitFrom(child, parent)` to the knowledge base.

Essentially, we want to see if, from some starting path id, a given `Artifact` object exists on all paths in the tree.  My attempt to o this is shown below:

```
query alwaysFinally( String $type, String $productName, long $parentPathId )
    Artifact( type == $type, productName == $productName, pathId == $parentPathId )
    or
    forall( SplitFrom( parent == $parentPathId, $childPathId := child )
      and
      ?alwaysFinally( $type, $productName, $childPathId; ) )
end
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Build Errors:
 Error Messages:
Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=edu/umn/crisys/sim/agent/cognition/futureworld/rules/process/antecedent/commonAntecedents.drl, line=47, column=0
   text=[ERR 102] Line 47:6 mismatched input '?' in query]
Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=edu/umn/crisys/sim/agent/cognition/futureworld/rules/process/antecedent/commonAntecedents.drl, line=0, column=0
   text=Parser returned a null Package]
...
```

I've played with inserting parenthesis in a number of different ways,  but I don't think that is the real problem.  If I remove the `and` and replace it with a comma or a newline, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.core.rule.QueryElement cannot be cast to org.drools.core.rule.Pattern

    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.ForallBuilder.build(ForallBuilder.java:57)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.ForallBuilder.build(ForallBuilder.java:32)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.GroupElementBuilder.build(GroupElementBuilder.java:66)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.GroupElementBuilder.build(GroupElementBuilder.java:36)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.GroupElementBuilder.build(GroupElementBuilder.java:66)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuilder.build(RuleBuilder.java:97)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addRule(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1820)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1111)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileAllRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:989)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildRules(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:260)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackages(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:121)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:105)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:243)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:64)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:230)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:198)
```

I don't think accumulators will work here since a query is not a Pattern object.

Does anyone have a good idea of how to express this in Drools?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the forall. This is something that Drools does automatically for all matches, to continue the matching process. forall is the universal quantifier which you don't need here since the condition need not be true for all of a set of facts.

```
query alwaysFinally( String $type, String $productName, long $parentPathId )
  Artifact( type == $type, productName == $productName, pathId == $parentPathId )
  or
  ( SplitFrom( parent == $parentPathId, $childPathId := child )
    and
    ?alwaysFinally( $type, $productName, $childPathId; )
end
```

It may result in multiple matches if the Artifact occurs more than once.

Comment: Perhaps I misexplained.   When I run it behaves as if the latter part of the "or" says: if there is a child path of a splitFrom with the given parent and the child path always finally contains the artifact, then return true.  In other words it behaves like it is existentially quantified.  What I want is for all children of splitFroms with the given parent and each child path (or path from it) contains the artifact, then return true.  I thought about collecting the child path ids then doing a forall on those, but again, invoking a query on it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Logic rules won out.  The latter part of the "or" statement can be represented as (using set notation)

```
let childPathIds: { SplitFrom(parent == $parentPathId, child := childPathId } 
forall x in childPathIds, P(x)
```

Now, we can doubly negate and preserve identity.  This gets us:

```
let childPathIds: { SplitFrom(parent == $parentPathId, child := childPathId } 
exists x in childPathIds, not P(x)
```

Thus, it can be represented in dools using the following

```
accumulate( SplitFrom( parent == $parentPathId, $childPathId := child );
                         $childPaths: collectSet( $childPathId ) )
and
// Set non-empty
exists( $childPathId: Long() from $childPaths )
and
( not( exists( $childPathId: Long( ) from $childPaths
       and
       not (?alwaysFinally( $type, $productName, $childPathId; ) ) ) )
)
```

Notice the additional non-empty check?  We need that because the 3rd condition will return true if `$childPaths` is empty.

So, moral of the story:  Yes, we can capture forall with a subquery; however we have to use a much more clunky syntax to do it.  At least we don't have to go down to Java to implement it.